# Cascaded discrete time system

Tags: signal, signal-processing

I would like to propose my answers to the following exercise and you tell me if I am right or not.

Exercise:
We consider the cascaded LTI system of Figure 1:

[image: cascaded system]
<sup>Figure 1</sup>

And the impulsional response \$h_2[n]=u[n]-u[n-2]\$ where \$u[n]\$ is a discrete Heaviside signal.
The global impulsional response of the system is shown in Figure 2:

[image: response of h1]
<sup>Figure 2</sup>

Questions:

1. Find the impulsional response \$h_1[n]\$.
2. Find the global response of the system if the input is \$x[n]=\delta[n]-\delta[n-1]\$.

Answer to first question:

Since the blocks of Figure 1 are in cascade, the global system \$h[n]=h_1\ast h_2[n]\ast h_2[n]\$ (\$\ast\$ is the symbol of convolution)
so \$H_2[z].H_2[z]=1+2z^{-1}+z^{-2}\$.

From Figure 2 we can obtain the Z transform of the global response: \$Y[z]=1+5z^{-1}+10z^{-2}+11z^{-3}+8z^{-4}+4z^{-5}+z^{-6}\$

From the properties of the Z transform in convolution we know that \$H[z]=H_1[z].H_2[z].H_2[z]\$ so \$H_1[z]=\frac{Y[z]}{H_2[z].H_2[z]}\$
\$H_1[z]=1+3z^{-1}+3z^{-2}+2z^{-3}+z^{-4}\$ and \$h_1[n]\$ is the discrete time signal defined by:
\$\small{h[n]=1~\mathrm{if}~n=0\\
h[n]=3~\mathrm{if}~n=1\\  
h[n]=3~\mathrm{if}~n=2\\  
h[n]=2~\mathrm{if}~n=3\\  
h[n]=1~\mathrm{if}~n=4\\  
h[n]=0~\mathrm{else}}\$

Answer to the second question:
No idea.